# How to check if part of my struct is 0 in range

Tags: range, go-templates

This is a part of my template file:

```
{{range .CartList}}
{{.ID}}
{{.Name}}
{{.Description}}
{{end}}
```

CartList is part of my Template Page Data it's a []model.Equipment

This is my Equipment Struct:

```
type Equipment struct {
    ID int
    Name string
    Description string
    ImgPath string
    Category string
    Availability bool
    Amount string
    Storage string
    Owner int
}
```

Basically I want to check if .ID is 0 and if this is the case it should display a message like: "No Articles in your Cart available"

Until now it shows an empty cart like this [0 false 0..

I also tried this:

```
{{if .CartList}}
{{range .CartList}}
BODY
{{else}}
"Cart not Available"
{{end}}
{{end}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you need to check if ID is 0? If you want to show an alternative message when there are no items inside of CartList, you can use the range-else syntax.

```
{{range .CartList}}
{{.ID}}
{{.Name}}
{{.Description}}
{{else}}
No Articles in your Cart available
{{end}}
```

Quoting the [documentation for `text/template`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/):

> If the value of the pipeline has length zero, dot is unaffected and
>   T0 is executed; otherwise, dot is set to the successive elements
>   of the array, slice, or map and T1 is executed.

You don't need to place this inside an if (like you did in OP). What you did in the last example of the OP would work if you moved one of the `{{end}}` lines above the `{{else}}`.

---

If you want to show a message if ID is 0:

```
{{range .CartList}}
    {{if .ID}}
        {{.ID}}
        {{.Name}}
        {{.Description}}
    {{else}}
        No Articles in your Cart available
    {{end}}
{{end}}
```

Comment: That is exactly what i was looking for. Thank you very much.

Comment: @ChristopherG1994 you might want to accept the answer then :)

Answer (score 0):

`{{if .CartList}} Body {{end}}` is what your'e looking for

Comment: It still shows me the empty <divs>. It seems like he still range throug CartList because it exist, but its nothing in it.